# terminating: loadlib libVisionProxy.dylib not available in /Users/priya/Library/Application Support/Sikulix/SikulixLibs_201510051707

Tags: sikuli

I have added below 2 dependencies in POM file for running a Sikuli program and getting the error

"loadlib: libVisionProxy.dylib not available  in /Users/priya/Library/Application Support/Sikulix/SikulixLibs_201510051707"

what should I do to fix this issue in my MAC system.

```
**Dependency added.**
'<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>'
```

In Maven dependency I can see the Jar added are
Sikuli-api 1.2.0 ,
Sikuli-core 1.2.2 ,
sikulixapi 2.0.4.,
sikulix2tigervnc 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

sikuli-api and sikulixapi are two different packages, that should not be used together. decide for one of them.

For SikuliX: Delete the folder /Users/priya/Library/Application Support/Sikulix/ and Strat all over again.